# actual disk iops and write merging

Tags: linux, performance, hard-drive

/dev/sdb has LVM and exposes a single logical volume, dm-0.

While writing to dm-0, /proc/diskstats reports:

```
# of writes completed
sdb 29646717
dm-0 131315099

# of writes merged:
sdb 101668283
dm-0 0
```

That means that /dev/sdb statistics report that most of the writes have been merged, so it report much lower total writes, while the lvm device does not. Which counters are more indicative of the actual write IOPS detected by the lower layer (e.g. AWS provisioned IOPS?)

Comment: AWS provioned IOPS are 16k, anything smaller counts as 1,  anything larger more than one, a 24k write would be 1.5. A server provisioned with 10,000 IOPS could do 2,500 64K IOs for example.

Comment: but if writes are 4K and are been merged let's say in 16K, does aws detect the 4K or the 16K writes (1/4). @Brian can you please indicate where did you find the documentation of how I/O < 16K is counted in AWS? thanks.

Comment: If the blocks are merged before they hit the block device (after that AWS takes over) then they would be 16k IOs. The documentation is the provisioned IOPS docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.html)